# Rails 5: Attempting to generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters - How to find params to whitelist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 5 and this link

```
 <%= link_to 'Pdf', payments_path(params.merge(format: :pdf)), :target => "_blank" %>
```

causes:

> Attempting to generate a URL from non-sanitized request parameters! An
>   attacker can inject malicious data into the generated URL, such as
>   changing the host. Whitelist and sanitize passed parameters to be
>   secure.

I have seen few questions on this issue already and how is the `.merge` that causes this.

For a while I just used  `params.permit!` to avoid to face the problem but obviously that's not a solution.

So I understand I have to whitelist necessary params.

Isn't enough to create the usual:

```
 def whatever_params
     params.require(:whatever).permit(.....)
end
```

and whitelist all necesssary params?

I'm new to rails and so far I whitelisted params for forms, so regarding POST parameteres. In that case I just include params used in form fields. But I understand this is regarding params on url, so query string parameters. So is this regarding params passed to url from ransack or will_paginate (gems I'm using)? This confuses me..

How do I exactly check which params need to be whitelisted to avoid to receive that error?

Comment: If you want to use params , you need to whitelist them like you have done in whatever_params method, you should not use the params directly in your controller. First whitelist them & then use.

Comment: Ok thanks but as I mentioned so far I did it for POST params used in forms. Which are easy to find. But this case seems to be about query string parameters. And I'm confused about how to identify them to be able to include them in my whatever_params method.

Comment: doesn't matter about the query string parameters, when you use the parameter just whitle list them , create a new function which whitelist your query string parameter & then use them

Comment: Let's put it this way. I have a controller with a view with a form. I create the whatever_params method with params included in the form. Everything works. Then I add the link I mentioned with `.merge`. And the error comes out. So my question is how do I find out which other parameters came into play? That button is to go to the pdf version done with prawn, and the .merge was added to have results in pdf filtered by ransack instead of showing all results. So does this mean that if I have a ransack filter :category it's enough to include :category on my whatever_params method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Yes. It's enough to create simple method like `whatever_params` and use `params.require(:whatever).permit(..)` or `params.permit(...)`

2.Move all params that you use to whitelist. For example, you have `GET` request with tons of params but use only some of them and they are optional:

```
def my_params
  params.permit(:category, :name, :age) #params that you use
end
```

Comment: Ok thanks this clears things a bit. But let's assume the database table in question has only 3 columns :category, :name and :age. In this case using the method in your example would fix the issue no matter what? Or are there possibly other parameters involved?  And if yes how do I find them? I checked the trace but I can't find any reference. Where should I look?

Comment: If you need params just for creating a new object - `:category, :name, :age` are enough. 

You can find all params in server log file. It looks like `Started GET "your_url" for ::1 at timestamp
Processing by YourController#method as HTML
 Parameters: {"param1"=>"1", "param2"=>"2"}` or create a breakpoint in controller method and look what inside `params` hash